# How can I index vividsolutions MultiPolygon object using java API in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to index MultiPolygon object using java API in elasticsearch. I already created mapping for it.

```
jsonBuilder.startObject("geom")
.field("type", "geo_shape")
.field("tree", "quadtree")
.field("precision", "1m")
.endObject()
```

But I don't know the easy way to index MultiPolygon object. I know the http way.

```
{
    "location" : {
        "type" : "multipolygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],
            [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],
            [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this? I really appreciate it.

Hailong

Answer (score 0):

Build it manually with an `XContentBuilder` returned from `jsonBuilder()`.

```
jsonBuilder()
  .startObject()
    .startObject("location")
      .field("type", "multipolygon")
      .startArray()
        .startArray()
          .startArray().value(102.0).value(2.0).endArray()
          // add the rest of the coordinates here as more arrays
          ...
        .endArray()
      .endArray()
    .endObject()
  .endObject();`
```

`jsonBuilder()` is available as a static import in `org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory`.

Once you've built that, index it with the Index API described here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index_.html